# Check if Vector has only same elements or -2 C++

Tags: c++, vector

I Have a vector which looks like:

```
{-2, -2, 4, 4, 6}   (Vector is not sorted!)
```

Now I want to create an if clause:

If the Vector contains only -2 or all the other elements are the same then it is a good vector.  If not then it is a bad vector

Example: So `{-2,1,1,1,1,-2}` would be okay, all 1 or -2, but `{-2,1,2,3,-2}` would be bad because besides the -2, the other elements are not the same.

So I tried it with std::find

```
if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), !-2 || !max) != subBinNo.end())
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not a good problem description. **How** doesn't it work? Also, please provide [mcve].

Comment: So you want to check if all elements in the vector are the same?

Comment: What do you think `!-2` or `!max` expressions do?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes but -2 to shouldn't be part of it.. so check only if the other elements are the same

Comment: @Arkadiy my idea was ... search for an element which is not -2 (!-2) and not the same like the max value of the vector.... so there is also a number in this vector which is non equal to the max value

Comment: @BoPersson no.. sometimes the -2 could be at the end or in the middle.. its totally random

Comment: So `{-2,1,1,1,1,-2}` would be okay, all 1 or -2 but `{-2,1,2,3,-2}` would be bad because besides the -2 the other elements are not the same?

Comment: @NathanOliver Right !

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Unfortunately, it's not that easy. You have no way of knowing ahead of time, at which index the first non-`-2` value is.

Comment: @Ildon - I know what you *tried* to say. But please give some thought to how the C++ compiler understands what you said. Please consider what `!-2` means TO THE COMPILER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution that does not require modifying your original `vector` is:

```
bool isVectorSame(std::vector<int> const& vector)
{
    bool result = true;

    const auto firstNot = std::find_if_not(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [](auto i) { return (i == -2); });

    if(firstNot != vector.end())
    {
        result = std::all_of(firstNot, vector.end(), [&](auto i) { return ((i == -2) || (i == (*firstNot))); });
    }

    return result;
}
```

The idea is as follows:

1. Find the first value `!= -2`*
2. Using [`std::all_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/), check if each value in the `vector` either equals `-2` or the value found in Step 1.

See it run [here](http://cpp.sh/5wtlw).

** If no value is found that `!= -2` then the vector is filled with `-2` and passes the test.*

Comment: Have you tried running the complete example I linked [here](http://cpp.sh/5wtlw)? What IDE/compiler are you using? `std::all_of` was introduced in C++11 and may not be available in older IDEs (VS2010, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is using a [`std:set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).  A `set` only contains unique values so if we copy the vector into the set only the unique elements will be in the set.  That means in your case the set needs to have a size of 2 if it contains -2 and another element otherwise if the size is 1 then the vector only contained the same element.  Doing that would give us code that looks like

```
bool unique_ignore_negative_two(const std::vector<int>& data)
{
    std::set<int> unique{data.begin(), data.end()};
    return (unique.size() == 1) || ( unique.size() == 2 && unique.count(-2) == 1);
}
```

Then you would use it like

```
if (unique_ignore_negative_two(vector_name)
{
    // do true stuff
}
else
{
    // do false stuff
}
```

Comment: @Ildon There was a typo in the code.  I have fixed it.  See this working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab5f973694d70464

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do:

```
bool test(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    auto r = v | ranges::view::filter([](int e) { return e != -2; });
    const auto p = ranges::minmax_element(r);

    return r.end() == p.first || *p.first == *p.second;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/275ffe16fee8952b)